# React native WebView Text Input from HTML shows a stage window on the bottom

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I want to do a normal WebView inside my RN app. The problem is that when I press inside a text input field a small window appear at the bottom of the screen, even on top of the BottomMenuBar saying "Done" in the right corner.
This should be the keyboard? What can be and how can I open the native keyboard in this case?

[image]

Comment: post the TextInput code

Comment: The TextImput is part of the HTML web page I am loading with the WebView

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I had to add `hideKeyboardAccessoryView={true}` to the WebView.